# Hibernate cant find the correct foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, hsqldb

I am having a problem that hibernate tries to drop foreign keys that dont exist instead of the one that exists. My scenario looks like this.

I want to run a junit tests, before ever test I want to create DB and after ever test I want to drop it. For that I use hibernate create-drop property. However the tricky part is that I want to create my own tables as a way to test newly added sql and verify that it will run fine once I deploy it to the production db server. So what happens is this

- Hibernate creates tables automatically
- Hibernate creates foreign key relationships
- Hibernate runs my drop table scripts (that succeeded since there is no data so no foreign key rule has been broken)
- Hibernate runs my create table scripts
- Hibernate runs my add foreign constraint scripts
- Hibernate runs my insert data scripts
- Test is executed
- Hibernate tries to remove the foreign key and it fails.

The reason hibernate has not be able to remove it is cause it tried to remove that one that hibernate created and not the one that was created by my scripts.

Any idea how to force hibernate to find out the actual foreign key? Any way to get around this problem?

Thanks everyone

Class for which hibernate creates the table

TodoGroup.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ToDoGroups")
public class ToDoGroup implements Serializable{


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "Name", length = 50)
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "UserSettingsId")
    @XmlTransient
    private UserSettings userSettings;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ToDoItem> items;
```

hibernate adding the constraint

```
alter table ToDoGroups 
        add constraint FK790BA1FAFE315596 
        foreign key (UserSettingsId) 
        references UserSettings
```

running my own tables that work fine since there is no data so I can remove what hibernate created in order to verify my sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ToDoGroups;

CREATE TABLE ToDoGroups (ID BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY, Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, UserSettingsId BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID));

ALTER TABLE ToDoGroups ADD FOREIGN KEY (UserSettingsID) REFERENCES UserSettings (ID);
```

drop fk it tries to execute

```
alter table ToDoGroups drop constraint FK790BA1FAFE315596
java.sql.SQLException: Constraint not found FK790BA1FAFE315596 in table: TODOGROUPS in statement [alter table ToDoGroups drop constraint FK790BA1FAFE315596]
```

tries to remove the table which fails due to the constrain that I have set in my create.sql script

```
    drop table ToDoGroups if exists
java.sql.SQLException: Table is referenced by a constraint in table SYS_REF_SYS_FK_808_810 table: TODOITEMS in statement [drop table ToDoGroups if exists]
```

Update

I have also noticed that hibernate when it first starts before it creates the tables (so this is way before my scripts are run), tries to remove foreign key in order to drop any table that exists.

So how does hibernate know what foreign key to use? It uses the same key that

first statement it executes

```
alter table ToDoGroups drop constraint FK790BA1FAFE315596
```

then it drops all of the tables

```
drop table ToDoGroups if exists
```

then it creates table

```
create table ToDoGroups (
    id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1),
    Name varchar(50),
    UserSettingsId bigint,
    primary key (id)
)
```

then it adds the same FK

```
alter table ToDoGroups 
    add constraint FK790BA1FAFE315596 
    foreign key (UserSettingsId) 
    references UserSettings
```

I think my question here is how does hibernate know what FK to use. It used the same FK in the first drop statement when there was even no table. Later it used that some FK to create the relationship. Shouldn't hibernate first check if the table exists and then tries to determine what is the FK?

Comment: using junit for this is not a good idea.

Comment: using junit to test business logic that happens to write out results into the db is not good idea? how come?

Comment: your business logic should not depend on database behaviour. JUnit is for good for business logic, but you shouldn't use it for database testing. There are other frameworks like dbunit for that.

Comment: well my business level saves the result into the db so then I need to access the db to verify the results. I guess I could split this into two parts and have one method above to take the results of the business layer and pass it to db, but lets say that for now I will stick to this (even if I change this and make my layer more complicated I will be left with the same problem and that is how to force hibernate to use the correct foreign key to forge about the one it created)

Comment: can you add some code about the foreign key to help me understand the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, your problem is that your own script and hibernate don't use the same constraint name.

You can specify a constraint name used by hibernate with this annotation on your relationship:

```
@ForeignKey(name = "fk_UserSettings")
```

And additionally, in your create.sql:

```
ALTER TABLE ToDoGroups ADD CONSTRAINT fk_UserSettings FOREIGN KEY (UserSettingsID) REFERENCES UserSettings (ID);
```

---

> I think my question here is how does hibernate know what FK to use. It used the same FK in the first drop statement when there was even no table. Later it used that some FK to create the relationship. Shouldn't hibernate first check if the table exists and then tries to determine what is the FK?

The foreign key name used by hibernate is the concatenation of

```
"FK_" + hashcode of referenced entity name + hash code of referenced columns name on that entity.
```

So it is not a randomly generated key (you will see that it will change if you change your entity name). And that's how hibernate knows the name of the fk to drop (hibernate is expecting that the constraint was created by hibernate with this well known naming strategy).

Hibernate use the name of the constraint to manipulate it. It don't compare the "rule" coded in constraints associated with a table to see if the constraint is already there or not.

Comment: so there is no way for hibernate to figure this out on its own?

Comment: You mean that you expect that hibernate to be able to see that you already have run a custom script on your database and specified constraint name in it ? (I'm still not sure to really understand the problem)

Comment: please read the last update, maybe it will make more sense then. But in short, yea I would expect for hibernate to check what is the FK used and not to use what ever it wants.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. In order to use custom fk I need to specify it, if not the hibernate will try to use its own. Tnx